# Display the correct answers in result(for wrong answered questns) of quiz app android

Tags: android

I currently have a quiz app which consists of a question & three multiple choice. At the end of every 10item quiz, the app displays the correct answers for all the 10item questions. Here's the code that i currently implement to display the answers in the result page

```
public static String getAnswers(List<Question> questions) {
    int question = 1;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (Question q : questions){
        sb.append("Q").append(question).append(") ").append(q.getQuestion()).append("? \n");
        sb.append("Answer: ").append(q.getAnswer()).append("\n\n");
        question ++;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

And i have these on my **QuestionActivity.java**

```
private void setQuestions() {
    questionCtr++;
    txtQNum.setText("Question " + questionCtr + " / 10");

    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);

    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    option1.setText(answers.get(0));

    TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    option2.setText(answers.get(1));

    TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    option3.setText(answers.get(2));

    radioGroup.clearCheck();
}


public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (!checkAnswer()) return;

    if (curQuiz.isGameOver()){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuizResult.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }
    else{
        currentQ = curQuiz.getNextQuestion();
        setQuestions();
    }
}

private boolean checkAnswer() {
    String answer = getSelectedAnswer();

    if (answer==null){

        return false;
    }
    else {

        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {

            curQuiz.incrementRightAnswers();
        }
        else{

            curQuiz.incrementWrongAnswers();
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private String getSelectedAnswer() {
    RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer3);

    if (c1.isChecked())
    {
        return c1.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c2.isChecked())
    {
        return c2.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c3.isChecked())
    {
        return c3.getText().toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What i wanted to do is to display **only** the correct answer for those Questions that have been answered **wrong** so it won't display unnecessary Q&A's which the user had answer correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a boolean flag `isAnswerCorrect` inside the `Question` class. Set it to `false` by default and each time the user guesses the correct answer for a question you make that flag `true`.

```
class Question {
    // ... other fields you already have here
    boolean isAnswerCorrect = false; // boolean flag for correct answer initialized to false

    // ... constructor, getters, setters

    public void setAnsweredCorrectly() {   // you use this method to set the answer to correct
        isAnswerCorrect = true;
    }

    public boolean isAnsweredCorrectly() {   // you will use this method to only get correct answers
        return isAnswerCorrect;
    }
}
```

You set an answer as correct inside the `if` statement of your `checkAnswer()` method:

```
// ...
if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
{
    curQuiz.incrementRightAnswers();
    currentQ.setAnsweredCorrectly(); // set the answer as correct here (boolean flag becomes true)
}
// ...
```

Then in your loop inside `getAnswers()`, just append the answers that weren't answered correctly:

```
// ...
for (Question q : questions){
    if(!q.isAnsweredCorrectly()) { // check here if the answer wasn't correct and append it
        sb.append("Q").append(question).append(") ").append(q.getQuestion()).append("? \n");
        sb.append("Answer: ").append(q.getAnswer()).append("\n\n");
        question ++;
    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: What code should i put into the `// check here if the answer wasn't correct` ? sorry. Really have no idea. I've already put the codes you've given though @nem

Comment: @KaitlinReyes hi, I edited my question to make things a little more clear to you